# ngSelect - Nesting options with arbitrary depth

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app I have an array of objects with the following structure

```
[{"ID":1, "parentID":0, "name":"Parent #1"}, 
{"ID":2, "parentID":0, "name":"Parent #2"}, 
{"ID":3, "parentID":1, "name":"Child #1 1"}, 
{"ID":4, "parentID":3, "name":"child #1 2"},
{"ID":5, "parentID":2, "name":"child #2 1"},
{"ID":6, "parentID":5, "name":"child #2 2"}]
```

I'd like to present this as a select menu which would allow a user to select a leaf node while still outputting non-selectable parent nodes to display the hierarchy of the structure.

I've tried a few approaches, the most successful of which was, in my angular template, something along the lines of the following.

```
<div ng-repeat="(idx, category) in $scope.allCats">
    <select ng-model="$scope.cats[idx]" 
            ng-options="cat as cat.name group by $scope.parentName(cat.parentID, idx) for cat in $scope.allCategories track by cat.ID">
        <option value="">Select A Category</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

`$scope.allCats` is the array above and `$scope.parentName()` method returns a string.

The troubles with this are demonstrated in the following screenshot. Namely all parent items appear twice, once as an `<option>` and once as an `<optgroup>`, whereas I'd rather they only appeared as a selectable item but with them being obviously a parent item, and the hierarchy of the structure is not maintained; child nodes with ancestors and descendants do not appear in the correct 'family-tree' structure.

[image: screenshot]

How can I alter my injected data or my angular template to achieve the behaviour I desire?

That is, to display the entire hierarchy, as defined by the `parentID` attributes so each family shares a common ancestor, and with parent items only appearing once.

I suspect this is being complicated by the fact there is more than one level of descendants possible and because I would like to keep this as general as possible.

Comment: jsfiddle would be nice!

Comment: a js fiddle, read your method "scope.parentName" could be useful to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about sorting the array in the scope before passing it to the angular template?. If you have:

```
var arr = [
  {"ID":1, "parentID":0, "name":"Parent #1"}, 
    {"ID":3, "parentID":1, "name":"Child #1 1"}, 
      {"ID":4, "parentID":3, "name":"child #1 2"},
        {"ID":7, "parentID":4, "name":"asdfadsf"},
  {"ID":2, "parentID":0, "name":"Parent #2"}, 
    {"ID":5, "parentID":2, "name":"child #2 1"},
      {"ID":6, "parentID":5, "name":"child #2 2"}
];
```

it would be easier. Just show it as it is.

### Code to sort:

```
var sortKeys = {};

// computes a unique sort key
function getSortKey(item) {
  if(sortKeys[item.ID] === undefined) {
    var parentItem = arr.filter(function(it) {
      return it.ID === item.parentID;
    })[0];

    if(parentItem != null) {
      return getSortKey(parentItem)  + '' + item.ID;
    }

    return item.parentID + '' + item.ID;
  }

  return sortKeys[item.ID];
}

// build sort keys to be used to sort items following their hierarchy
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  sortKeys[item.ID] = getSortKey(item);
});

// sort the array
arr.sort(function(item1, item2) {    
  var item1SortKey = sortKeys[item1.ID],
      item2SortKey = sortKeys[item2.ID];

  return item1SortKey < item2SortKey ?
    -1 :
    (item1SortKey > item2SortKey ?
      1:
      0);
});
```

```js
var arr = [{"ID":1, "parentID":0, "name":"Parent #1"}, 
{"ID":2, "parentID":0, "name":"Parent #2"}, 
{"ID":3, "parentID":1, "name":"Child #1 1"}, 
{"ID":4, "parentID":3, "name":"child #1 2"},
{"ID":5, "parentID":2, "name":"child #2 1"},
{"ID":6, "parentID":5, "name":"child #2 2"},
{"ID":7, "parentID":4, "name":"asdfadsf"}];

var sortKeys = {};

// computes a unique sort key
function getSortKey(item) {
  if(sortKeys[item.ID] === undefined) {
    var parentItem = arr.filter(function(it) {
      return it.ID === item.parentID;
    })[0];

    if(parentItem != null) {
      return getSortKey(parentItem)  + '' + item.ID;
    }

    return item.parentID + '' + item.ID;
  }
  
  return sortKeys[item.ID];
}

// build sort keys to be used to sort items following their hierarchy
arr.forEach(function(item) {
  sortKeys[item.ID] = getSortKey(item);
});

// sort the array
arr.sort(function(item1, item2) {    
  var item1SortKey = sortKeys[item1.ID],
      item2SortKey = sortKeys[item2.ID];
  
  return item1SortKey < item2SortKey ?
    -1 :
    (item1SortKey > item2SortKey ?
      1:
      0);
});

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a filter function.

For this example, I have simplified your data by changing the ParentID to be the actual parent name. 
(You use a function to replace this but concept is the same)

Data:

```
$scope.data = [{ "ID": 1, "parentID":"Parent #1", name: "Parent #1" }, 
            { "ID": 2, "parentID": "Parent #1", name: "Parent #2" }, 
            { "ID": 3, "parentID": "Parent #2", name: "Child #1 1" }, 
            { "ID": 4, "parentID": "Parent #3", name: "child #1 2" },
            { "ID": 5, "parentID": "Parent #3", name: "child #2 1" },
            { "ID": 6, "parentID": "Parent #6", name: "child #2 2" }]
```

View:

```
<select ng-model="data"
        ng-options="d as d.name group by d.parentID for d in data  | filter:checkparent(d)"></select>
```

Notice we have added a call to a function which will be used to filter the list. 
This is the function within the controller:

```
$scope.checkparent = function () {

            return function (d) {
                return d.name != d.parentID;
            }
        }
```

And this would be the result:

[image]

For your exact case, you can call your function that returns the Parent name inside the filter function, something like:

(not 100% sure what your function does but hope the concept is clear)

```
$scope.checkparent = function () {

                return function (d) {
                    return d.name != $scope.parentName(d.parentID, idx);
                }
            }
```